# How to use a native sql prepared statement to prepare column names

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

For testing purposes, I need a native SQL prepared statement which prepares on a column

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` where  ? > 10000';
SET @a = AVG_ROW_LENGTH;
Execute stmt using @a;
```

this doesnt work, as  #1054 - Unknown column 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH' in 'field list'
(same, if I put ` around the colname)

the error doesnt seem legit, as the following returns a result

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` where AVG_ROW_LENGTH > ?';
SET @a = 10000;
Execute stmt using @a;
```

Do you know if there's a special syntax, or if it just doesnt work?
**Thanks!**

version infos:

```
    Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server type: MariaDB
    Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
    Server version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.13
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

Comment: You can't use parameters for column names, only for values.

Comment: Build the SQL string before you PREPARE it.

Comment: it's a dynamic query, would have been cool, if things could be done on DB side, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next approach:

```
SET @condition = 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH';
SET @value = 10000;

PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` where ',  @condition , ' > ?');

Execute stmt using @value;
```

Also you you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` where ',  @condition , ' > ?') USING @value;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f2d1cc7df860671086db7da1bd5b966e&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)